# How to change background of TabbedPage's invidually in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: background, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I tried to change BarBackgroundColor property but only first case of switch is working and setting color purple. CurrentPageChanged event is firing but not changing background color. Additionally how to change invidially background of single tab background.

In my `public partial class Tabbed : TabbedPage`

```
    public void changeColorOfTabBar(int index)
    {      
        switch (index)
        {
            case 0:
                BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex(Constants.evrensel_purple);
                break;
            case 1:
                BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex(Constants.evrensel_green);
                break;
            case 2:
                BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex(Constants.evrensel_blue);
                break;
            default:
                BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex(Constants.color_blue);
                break;
        }
    }
    public void createTabs(LoginResponse response)
    {

        Children.Add(new HomeTab(response) { Title = "Home", Icon = "home.png" });
        Children.Add(new TimesheetTab(response) { Title = "Timesheet", Icon = "timesheet.png" });
        Children.Add(new MyLeavesTab(response) { Title = "My Leaves", Icon = "leave.png", });
    }
    public Tabbed (LoginResponse response,LoggedInfo info)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Title = "Welcome, " + _serviceEmployee.getEmployeeByUserId(response.userid).fullnameReplaced;
        CurrentPageChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var index = Children.IndexOf(CurrentPage);
            changeColorOfTabBar(index);
        };
        createTabs(response);

        res = response;           
    }
```

Comment: Try calling it on the static NavigationPage object, like `NavigationPage.BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex(Constants.evrensel_purple);`

Comment: It is not possible or I dont understand you. Can you give more detail please?

Comment: Instead of this line `case 0:
                BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex(Constants.evrensel_purple);` try `case 0:
                NavigationPage.BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex(Constants.evrensel_purple);`